# Beginning Counterpoint

Tags: theory

Can I start a 5th species counterpoint on a perfect 12th instead of a perfect 5th when the cantus firmus is in the lower voice?[image]

Comment: The example does not make clear what the lower voice is doing.  From the A5 to the second C5 there is only one voice.  Does the lower voice rest?  Does it sustain the F?  Are the notes from beat 2 to 4 of the second measure for the lower voice?  If so what does the upper voice do?  Starting with a 12th is among the least of the problems here.  If the two voices were shown distinctly, it would be possible to decide whether simply lowering the upper voice by an octave would solve the problem of the 12th or whether another solution might be possible.

Answer (score 2):

In strict terms, no. One of basic rules underlying all of the species is to keep both voices within an octave of each other, although tenths are permissible.

However, for the purposes of one's own learning, it's fine, because the concepts being reinforced in fifth species still apply. The thing on which one misses out is the compositional challenge of limiting the range of the voices, which is valuable in itself as preparation for composition beyond exercises.

Comment: The perfect 12th is actually allowable "within" the counterpoint, and Fux uses it as well as the P11th in many situations; it's the Major13th that exceeds the threshold of strict counterpoint in 2voices. Your understanding of the Contrapunctus seems limited. Starting on the perfect 12th would allow me to modulate from Cmajor to Fmajor without leaping by a fourth to arrive at the subsequent tonic(which is stylistically attractive to me because leaps less than a third do not require compensation).

Comment: *In my opinion, the ranges of strict counterpoint should not be further limited because the compound intervals give more variety in the permutations of harmonies(would you really want to just hear 3rds, 5ths, and 8ves in your "perfect world" of instinctively limiting the ranges?....answer is no. You should be lucky that you can hear a Ma10,Mi10, Ma3, Mi3, P5th and P12 because that allows muchhhh more HARMONY.) The independence lost by preferring a P5 to a P12th should be of no consequence, because the rules determined its stability.

Comment: *P.S. I would never actually start on a P12 but I was just curious ,as a pianist and theorist, why the compound version of the unison(obviously the 8ve) can begin the counterpoint but the compound version of the 5th does not, especially if the 12th won't be exceeded anyways...if we're talking about independence of lines, then wider intervals should be preferred to discourage voice crossing which is the real problem that Fux could not even avoid.

Comment: @JDWashington Your points are well taken, but also demonstrate your own limited understanding. Fux was not writing within the context of tonality, nor does he consider the modulations you have in mind. His model was Palestrina, who wrote modally and who is not known to have written instrumental music. Palestrina-style, sacred vocal music was the central motivation for Fux.

Comment: P.S. It's been some time since I last studied Fux, but I don't recall seeing intervals greater than a 10th between adjacent voices, which is what I interpreted your question to address, since the example comprises two voices.

Comment: @JDWashington you can totally start on a 12th if there are multiple voices.  The thing with this style of counterpoint, though, is that you lose the sense of blending of the voices if two adjacent voices are separated by so much.  A piece for soprano instrument (flute, violin, etc.) or voice with basso continuo accompaniment will routinely include larger intervals, but that is far enough outside the scope of "species counterpoint" that the interval-size rule is relaxed (and the continuo realisation fills the gap, anyway).